# create combobox with current month selected in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, combobox

I am trying to create a combo box in angular for months with current month as selected. I have tried the following

`<select data-ng-init="searchObj.searchMon = months[{currMonth}]"   data-ng-model="searchObj.searchMon" data-ng-options="mon as mon.label for mon in months">`

where currMonth is defined in scope as the index of the current month in months array. Help me to complete achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace `months[{currMonth}]` with `months[currMonth]`